# find multiple datas between two string in python in a paragraph

Tags: python, regex, string

I am reading a text file which has data  like this string input:
String input :

```
string = """unwanted strings

/start INPUT_DATA
    input_data_Name_One  input_data_Name_two
/end INPUT_DATA
unwanted string
/start OUTPUT_DATA 
    ouput_data_Name_One  ouput_data_Name_Two 
/end OUTPUT_DATA
unwanted string
/start LOC_DATA   
    loc_Data_Name_One  loc_data_Name_Two  loc_data_Name_Three
/end LOC_DATA
unwanted string
/start LOC_THING   
    no_Need_One no_Need_Two  no_Need_Three
/end LOC_THING

unwanted strings"""
```

```
matches = re.findall('start(.*?)end', string, re.DOTALL)
```

I tried with many expressions but newline,special charecters giving errors
how to escape it.

expected output:

```bash
 ['input_data_Name_One' ,'input_data_Name_two','ouput_data_Name_One','ouput_data_Name_Two','loc_Data_Name_One','loc_data_Name_Two','loc_data_Name_Three']
```

Comment: how to take DATA also a important in filter /start in_DATA /end in_DATA is acceptable and /start in_THING /end in_THING is not acceptable. Like DATA should be in same line as start

Comment: please update your question to make it clear

Comment: question updated `/start LOC_THING   
    no_Need_One no_Need_Two  no_Need_Three
/end LOC_THING` this lines should not include in output  `print ( [s.split() for s in re.findall(r'/start .*\s+((?:.+\n)+?)/end ', string)] )` this code will take the above code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `findall + split` approach:

```py
import re

string = """unwanted strings

/start INPUT_DATA
    input_data_Name_One  input_data_Name_two
/end INPUT_DATA
unwanted string
/start OUTPUT_DATA 
    ouput_data_Name_One  ouput_data_Name_Two
/end OUTPUT_DATA
unwanted string
/start LOC_THING
          no_Need_One no_Need_Two  no_Need_Three
/end LOC_THING

/start LOC_DATA   
    loc_Data_Name_One  loc_data_Name_Two  loc_data_Name_Three
/end LOC_DATA

unwanted strings"""

print ( [s.split() for s in re.findall(r'/start .*_DATA\s+((?:.+\n)+?)/end ', string)] )
```

**Output:**

```bash
[['input_data_Name_One', 'input_data_Name_two'], ['ouput_data_Name_One', 'ouput_data_Name_Two'], ['loc_Data_Name_One', 'loc_data_Name_Two', 'loc_data_Name_Three']]
```

Here:

- We use `findall` to match 1+ lines between `/start` line that ends with `_DATA` and another line with `/end` keywords.
- Then we use `split` to split matches on whitespaces.

Comment: how to take DATA also a important in filter  /start in_DATA  /end in_DATA is acceptable and /start in_THING  /end in_THING is not acceptable

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
list(filter(None,re.findall(r'(\w+_[dD]ata_[_\w]+|)', string )))

['input_data_Name_One', 'input_data_Name_two', 'ouput_data_Name_One', 'ouput_data_Name_Two', 'loc_Data_Name_One', 'loc_data_Name_Two', 'loc_data_Name_Three']Name_Three']
```

Comment: how to take DATA also a important in filter /start in_DATA /end in_DATA is acceptable and /start in_THING /end in_THING is not acceptable